# .NET RegularExpression DataAnnotation Attribure Not Matching Correctly

Tags: c#, .net, regex, validation, data-annotations

I can find plenty of information on Regular Expressions for .NET, but not specifically for the RegularExpression attribute. From what I can see, it behaves differently than normal .NET RegEx.

I am trying to use data annotation validation to validate my product name ViewModel field. The rules are:

1. No leading or trailing spaces in the string.
2. Only allow upper and lower case characters and numbers.
3. No more than a single space between each word.

`This is good 123`

`This   is  not    good`

`this  $%^&*   is not good`

`123 this 555 good`

This will be single line since it is a product title.

The regular expression I think I need is
`[RegularExpression(@"([a-zA-Z0-9]+ ?)+?", ErrorMessage = "The product name can only contain letters, numbers, and a single space between each word")]`

But when I start typing a second word, the data annotation says my product name is invalid.

[image]

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you _need_ to use a regular expression attribute? It might be easier to write and understand with your own validation attribute that doesn't use regex.

Comment: @gunr2171, I also have fluent validation setup in my project, so I could use fluent validation, but I thought regex might be easier. I like the instant feedback of the data annotation validation in this case. I don't want the user to have to submit the form and then find out they have errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like issue is caused by ending `?` in `@"([a-zA-Z0-9]+ ?)+?"` which matches the previous element zero or one time.

Updating expression to `@"([a-zA-Z0-9]+ ?)+"` will give result as expected.

Follow [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference - .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem, but I am confused. I used https://regex101.com/ to validate my expression. According to that website, which is obviously wrong, the +? means: +? matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy). Is that statement wrong, or do I misunderstand?

Comment: Never mind. I think I missed as few times as possible. That's why it wasn't working.